# Laundry (noun) is the washing of clothing and linens. what do we call the laundry after laundering?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

While reading a chapter on laundry and the various techniques associated with it, it reflected that the clothes lined for washing were termed as laundry and so were the washed/ironed clothes.

Could there be a word or specific term to denote the washed/ironed linen.

Comment: I just call it "clean laundry".

Comment: 'Clean linen' would be the most likely term in Britain I suspect. It is interesting that the word 'linen', a very specific textile, has taken on a generic role to describe collectively things made of cotton, artificial fibre etc.

Comment: Or *clean clothes*.  In our family we put *dirty laundry* into the washing machine and we take *clean clothes* out of the dryer.

Comment: I would just say "clean washing". (In my version of British English the things to be washed, or which have been washed, are "washing", not "laundry").

Comment: It's still "the laundry".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Laundered linen" is what i would use.

Comment: +1. I was going to say that. "Laundered" covers "washed, folded and ironed" even.

Answer (score 0):

We wash to remove dirt, post laundering, it would make sense to call them:

- CLEAN
- NEAT

and similar simple words.

Comment: The question is not about a description of the washed clothes, but a term for them. In any case, "neat" would not be appropriate unless they had been ironed.

Answer (score 0):

In industrial laundries there are also the processes of drying (or tumble drying) and dry cleaning. They (the laundry machine, detergent manufacturers and the service providers) mostly use the common term "Laundry" for all of the laundry (linen) processing steps but when they have to specify the type of the laundry, they use the specific term. They don't distinguish between the states (phases) of the laundry.